# Can I use a 3.5'' hard drive on a notebook with a psu and a sata-e-sata cable?

Tags: external-hard-drive, esata

I have a spare 3.5" HDD at home and I want to use it on my notebook. My notebook have a e-sata port and I have a sata-e-sata cable, if I use the e-sata cable with a computer psu, can I use it on my notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes

**Some detail:**
You need to juryrig the PSU to provide power to the harddrive, without requiring a motherboard to turn it on. While this juryrigging is outside of the scope of this answer, it's not that hard, and you can find guides on how to do so around the web. It basically means gutting the ATX connector on the PSU and shorting a few pins. Beware that some PSUs have sens-wires used to measure the actual voltage it supplies, and these can just be tied to the corresponding wires.
What this means in practice are two main points:

- Unless you can get your hands on an old AT power supply, it means sacrificing a PSU.
- You probably want one with a main switch on the back, so that you can turn it off without having to pull the plug on it.

When connecting it all, apply power to it, and let the harddrive spin up a few seconds before connecting the e-sata cable. Otherwise your OS will think it's a faulty drive.

Sources:

1. I've juryrigged PSUs to serve as 12V desk supply for electronics
2. Some contraption at my old job involved externally powered 3.5" harddrives.

Comment: In the past I've just jumpered the gray PWR_OK pin to ground with a paperclip.

Comment: It's what's I'm doing right now

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There are also commercially-available enclosures which do basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the drive is powered, it shouldn't be an issue. I would recommend a 3.5" USB SATA HD Enclosure instead. They're really cheap.